# VS code c++ debugger setup using GDB does not work

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

So here's my problem. I have downloaded mingw g++ by using msys according to the [official vs code website](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)

Here are my files:

[image: Tasks.json]

[image: Settings.json]

[image: c_cpp_properties.json]

[image: launch.json]

Now, when I try to build I get this error:

```
> Executing task: g++ -std=c++14 -g -o myfile.exe myfile.cpp <

cc1plus.exe: fatal error: myfile.cpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command g++ -std=c++14 -g -o myfile.exe myfile.cpp" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

And if I do have a .exe file:

[image: .exe]
[image: files]

edit: I also started getting errors with

```
#include <iostream>
```

Comment: where is `myfile.cpp`? Why can't you copy/paste the content of the files in the images

Comment: I cannot copy paste beacsue than stackoverflow syas "You need to write more about the error and less in codeblocks"
And the thing is that there is no myfile.cpp and idk what the error is.

Comment: what is it with `myfile.exe` and `03.exe` and there cpp files

Comment: Honestly, idk. I am new to this and I am just following tutorials. I know c++ basics but I was using my old af ubuntu laptop before and now I am switching to windows

Comment: in `tasks.json` you hard code to compile `myfile.cpp` and in `launch.json` you use the current file but you don't set a `preLaunchTask`

Comment: windows or ubuntu does not matter in setting up VSC for C++, maybe you use a different compiler

Comment: I have no idea what that means ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: compiler is just from a tutorial from the official website tbh idk what to do

Comment: then you have to read the doc pages of VSC again about these terms

Comment: I know what compiler means, but I don't know why my it doesn't work rn

Comment: what is the need of the `files.associations` setting, you use it incorrect

Comment: I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make this a comment if I could. What is the name of the file where you have written `#include <iostream>`?* I think if you change the name of that file to "myfile.cpp", you might stop getting that error. You will probably get a different error saying that "main() cannot be found" or something like that, but that's an improvement from your current spot.

*I see it's O3.cpp. Try changing that to myfile.cpp.

Comment: After doing so I get error about a .exe file for it not existing